# Camera 2 Api preview is stretched

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

I work with old camera api and camera 2 api, using GlSurfaceView.
when I get necessary aspect ratio in old api I use
 Camera.Parameters

```
camParams.setPreviewSize(previewW, previewH);
       if(isPictureSizeSupported(camParams, newSize)) {
           camParams.setPictureSize(newSize.getWidth(), newSize.getHeight());
       }
```

if it will not be called, preview is streched

Q: How to get such effect in camera 2 api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I migrate to `SurfaceView` and used `setFixedSize()` on `SurfaceHolder`. 
As [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html)  says:

> For drawing to a SurfaceView: Once the SurfaceView's Surface is
>   created, set the size of the Surface with setFixedSize(int, int) to be
>   one of the sizes returned by getOutputSizes(SurfaceHolder.class) and
>   then obtain the Surface by calling getSurface()